# Is it possible to use increments of two and use padding zeros on mc/insert-numbers?

Tags: multiple-cursors

I'm using `mc/insert-numbers` quite often for numbering classes on html. I know that I can use <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `mc/insert-numbers` to start counting from 6, but how could I use it to create a list like:

```
06
08
10
12
14
16
18
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mc/insert-numbers` has the increment and number format
hard-coded, but you can use this `mc/insert-fancy-numbers` command
instead. It'll prompt for start, step and format specifier; for your
example you'd answer `6`, `2` and `%02d`, respectively:

```
(defvar mc--insert-fancy-numbers-increment 1)
(defvar mc--insert-fancy-numbers-format "%d")

(defun mc/insert-fancy-numbers (start step format)
  "Insert increasing numbers for each cursor, starting from START,
counting by STEP and formatting them with the FORMAT specifier."
  (interactive "nStarting number: \nnIncrement: \nsFormat specifier (RET for '%%d'): ")
  (setq mc--insert-numbers-number start)
  (setq mc--insert-fancy-numbers-increment step)
  (setq mc--insert-fancy-numbers-format
        (if (string= format "") "%d" format))
  (mc/for-each-cursor-ordered
   (mc/execute-command-for-fake-cursor 'mc--insert-fancy-number-and-increase cursor)))

(defun mc--insert-fancy-number-and-increase ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format mc--insert-fancy-numbers-format mc--insert-numbers-number))
  (setq mc--insert-numbers-number
        (+ mc--insert-numbers-number mc--insert-fancy-numbers-increment)))
```